# How a standard library differ from user defined header file (.h) and its implementation file (.c) in C?

Tags: c, static-libraries, header-files

How a standard library like libc.a (static library) which is included using `#include <stdio.h>` in our main.c differ from user defined header file (cube.h) included in main.c with its implementation file (cube.c) in C ?

I mean both are header files but one's implementation is a static library (.a) and others is source file (.c) .

You would have the definition (implementation) in, say, cube.c

```
#include "cube.h"

int cube( int x ) {
   return x * x * x;
}
```

Then we'll put the function declaration in another file. By convention, this is done in a header file, cube.h in this case.

```
int cube( int x );
```

We can now call the function from somewhere else, main.c for instance, by using the #include directive (which is part of the C preprocessor) .

```
#include "cube.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
  int c = cube( 10 );
  printf("%d", c);
  ...
}
```

Also if I included include guards in cube.h what would happen when I include cube.h in both main.c and cube.c . Where it will get included?

Comment: There's very little difference between user-defined headers and system-defined ones.  Pretty much the same techniques you use to construct the code for your functions are the techniques used by the system maintainers to create the code for libc.a.  (They also have some special techniques available to them that you can't/shouldn't use, but those are implementation details; you could write a decent approximation of libc.a using pretty much pure C, if you set your mind to it.)

Comment: The statement that "a standard library like libc.a is included using `#include <stdio.h>`" is extremely imprecise and misses all the important details. Everything you're describing is the *linking* process of your tool chain, which is largely separate from the language specification beyond the fact that the spec says "this must work".

Answer (score 3):

A programming language is not the same as its implementation.

A programming language is a specification (written on paper; you should read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), which practically is the C11 standard), it is *not* a software. The C standard specifies a C standard library and defines the headers to be `#include`-d.

<sup>(you could run your C program with a bunch of human slaves and without any computers; that would be very unethical; you could also use some interpreter like [Ch](https://www.softintegration.com/download/) and avoid any compiler or object or executable files)</sup>

> How a standard library like `libc.a` (static library) which is included using `#include <stdio.h>` ... differs from a user file `cube.c`

The above sentence is utterly wrong (and makes no sense). `libc.a` does not `#include` -or is not included by- the `<stdio.h>` header (i.e. file `/usr/include/stdio.h`  and other internal headers e.g. `/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h`). That inclusion happens when *you* compile *your* `main.c` or `cube.c`.

In principle, `<stdio.h>`  might not be any file on your computer (e.g. `#include <stdio.h>` could trigger some magic in your compiler). In practice, the compiler is parsing `/usr/include/stdio.h` (and other included files) when you `#include <stdio.h>`.

Some standard headers (notably `<setjmp.h>`, `<stdreturn.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, ....)  are specified by the standard but are implemented with the help of special [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) or [attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) (that is "magic" things) of the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler.

The C standard knows about [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler processes [source files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) (grossly speaking, implementing translation units) and starts with a [preprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) phase (processing [`#include`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive)  and other directives and expanding macros). And `gcc` runs not only the compiler proper (some `cc1`) but also the assembler `as` and the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) `ld` (read Levine's [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://linker.iecc.com/) book for more).

For good reasons, your header file `cube.h`  should practically start with [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). In your simplistic example they are probably useless (but you should get that habit).

You practically should almost always use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (to get all warnings and debug info). Read the chapter about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

You may pass also `-v`  to `gcc`  to understand what programs (e.g. `cc1`, `ld`, `as`) are actually run.

You may pass `-H`  to `gcc`  to understand what source files are included during preprocessing phase. You can also get the preprocessed form of `cube.c`  as the `cube.i` file obtained with `gcc -C -E cube.c > cube.i`  and later look into that `cube.i` file with some editor or pager.

You -or `gcc`- would need (in your example) to compile `cube.c` (the translation unit given by that file and every header files it is `#include`-ing) into the `cube.o` [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) (assuming a Linux system). You would also compile `main.c` into `main.o`. At last `gcc` would link `cube.o`, `main.o`, some startup files (read about [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)) and the `libc.so` shared library (implementing the POSIX C standard library specification and a bit more) to produce an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable). [Relocatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) object files, shared [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries) (and static libraries, if you use some) and executables use the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file format on Linux.

If you code a C program with several source files (and translation units) you practically should use a [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

> If I included include guards in cube.h what would happen when I include cube.h in both main.c and cube.c ?

These should be two different translation units. And you would compile them in several steps. First you compile `main.c`  into `main.o` using

```
 gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c main.c
```

and the above command is producing a `main.o` object file (with the help of `cc1`  and `as`)

Then you compile (another translation unit) `cube.c` using

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c cube.c
```

hence obtaining `cube.o`

<sup>(notice that adding include guards in your `cube.h`  don't change the fact that it would be read twice, once when compiling `cube.c`  and the other time when compiling `main.c`)</sup>

At last you link both object files into `yourprog`  executable using

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g cube.o main.o -o yourprog
```

(I invite you to try all these commands, and also to try them with `gcc -v`  instead of `gcc`  above).

Notice that `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g cube.c main.c -o yourprog` is running all the steps above (check with `gcc -v`). You really should write a [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) to avoid typing all these commands (and just compile using `make`, or even better `make -j` to run compilation in parallel).

Finally you can run your executable using `./yourprog` (but read about [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))), but you should learn how to use `gdb`  and try `gdb ./yourprog`.

> Where it `cube.h` will get included?

It will get included at both translation units; once when running  `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c main.c`  and another time when running `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c cube.c`. Notice that object files (`cube.o` and `main.o`) don't contain included headers. Their debug information (in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format) retains that inclusion (e.g. the included path, not the content of the header file).

BTW, look into existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (and study some of their source code, at least for inspiration). You might look into GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) to understand what a C standard library really contains on Linux (it is built above [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), provided and implemented by the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel)). For example `printf` would ultimately *sometimes* use [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) but it is [buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) (see [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.2.html)).

PS. Perhaps you dream of programming languages (like Ocaml, Go, ...) knowing about [modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming). C is not one.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: the most crucial difference between the **C standard library** and *your* library function is that the compiler might intimately know what the standard library functions do without seeing their definition.

---

First of all, there are 2 kinds of libraries:

1. The C standard library (and possibly other libraries that are part of the C implementation, like `libgcc`)
2. Any other libraries - which includes all those other libraries in `/usr/lib`, `/lib`, etc.., or those in your project.

The most crucial difference between **a library in category 1** and **a library in category 2** library is that **the compiler is allowed to assume that *every* single identifier that you use from category 1 library *behaves* as if it is the standard library function and behaves as if in the standard** and can use this fact to optimize things as it sees fit - this even without it actually *linking* against the relevant routine from the standard library, or executing it at the runtime. Look at this example:

```
% cat foo.c 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%f\n", sqrt(4.0));
}
```

We compile it, and run:

```
% gcc foo.c -Wall -Werror
% ./a.out 
2.000000
%
```

and correct result is printed out.

So what happens when we ask the user for the number:

```
% cat foo.c 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double n;
    scanf("%lf\n", &n);
    printf("%f\n", sqrt(n));
}
```

then we compile the program:

```
% gcc foo.c -Wall -Werror
/tmp/ccTipZ5Q.o: In function `main':
foo.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Surprise, it doesn't link**. That is because `sqrt` is in the math library `-lm` and you need to link against it to get the definition. But how did it work in the first place? Because the **C compiler is free to assume that any function from standard library behaves as if it was as written in the standard**, so it can optimize all invocations to it out; this even when we weren't using any `-O` switches.

---

Notice that it isn't even necessary to include the header. [C11 7.1.4p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p2) allows this:

> Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its associated header.

Therefore in the following program, the compiler can still assume that the `sqrt` is the one from the standard library, and the behaviour here is still conforming:

```
% cat foo.c
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
double sqrt(double x);

int main(void) {
    printf("%f\n", sqrt(4.0));
}
% gcc foo.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror
% ./a.out
2.000000
```

---

If you drop the prototype for `sqrt`, and compile the program,

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);

int main(void) {
    printf("%f\n", sqrt(4));
}
```

A conforming C99, C11 compiler must diagnose constraint violation for implicit function declaration. The program is now an **invalid program**, but it still compiles (the C standard allows **that too**). GCC still calculates `sqrt(4)` at compilation time. Notice that we use `int` here instead of `double`, so it wouldn't even work at runtime without proper declaration for an ordinary function because without prototype the compiler wouldn't know that the argument must be `double` and not the `int` that was passed in (without a prototype, the compiler doesn't know that the `int` must be *converted to a `double`*). But it **still works**.

```
% gcc foo.c -std=c11 -pedantic
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:4:20: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sqrt’
             [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     printf("%f\n", sqrt(4));
                    ^~~~
foo.c:4:20: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘sqrt’
foo.c:4:20: note: include ‘<math.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘sqrt’
% ./a.out
2.000000
```

This is because an implicit function declaration is one with *external linkage*, and C standard says this [(C11 7.1.3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3):

> [...] All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) and `errno` are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage. [...]

and [Appendix J.2.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) explicitly lists as undefined behaviour:

> [...] The program declares or defines a reserved identifier, other than as allowed by 7.1.4 (7.1.3).

I.e. if the program did actually have its own `sqrt` then the behaviour is simply undefined, because the compiler can assume that the `sqrt` is the standard-conforming one.

Comment: The compiler can (and should) make the initial assumption only if the right *standard headers* are included (at the right place).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that's incorrect. "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) and errno are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage."

Comment: Then, C11 forbids implicit function declarations, but you can define it explicitly.