# Why does sqrt function not work for values taken through user input?

Tags: c, sqrt

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long int a;
    scanf("%lld", &a);
    printf("%lf", sqrt(a));
    return 0;
}
```

gives output:

```
source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
source_file.c:9:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     scanf("%lld", &a);
     ^
/tmp/ccWNm2Vs.o: In function `main':
source.c:(.text.startup+0x65): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, if I do `long long int a = 25;` and delete the `scanf` statement, or simply do `sqrt(25)`, both of them work (correctly give output `5.000000`).

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613191/why-does-sqrt-work-fine-on-an-int-variable-if-it-is-not-defined-for-an-int), but it is for C++ and uses function overloading, whereas afaict C does not have function overloading (that's why we have `sqrtf`, `sqrt`, `sqrtl` if I'm not wrong). Moreover, the above code fails whether I take `long long int` or `double` type of `a`. So, the questions are probably not related.
Also, regarding the other [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409032), the error did not occur for me for constantly defined values, which instead happens to be the case with the linked question.

What is the reason then? Why would a constant value work for `sqrt`, while a variable user input value won't?

Comment: Have you link with `-lm` For e.g `gcc -Wall test.c -lm` ?

Comment: This is a longstanding gcc bug (aka. weird design decision)

Comment: @Achal Yes, I tried, still doesn't work :(

Comment: show your exact build command and gcc version

Comment: Also you should `-std=c99` (or later e.g. `-std=c11`) since using `long long`

Comment: @M.M `-Wall  -lm -std=gnu99 -O2 -o a.out source_file.c` I also tried with `-Wall  -lm -o a.out source_file.c` without success.

Comment: @GaurangTandon `-lm` must come at the end, as suggested by Achal

Comment: @M.M Oh, ok that worked. Thanks!

Comment: @GaurangTandon I've explained the constant case in depth in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46016708/918959)

Comment: When a comment points out that more information is required, that information should be added to the question, not hidden in a comment.  Edit the question to add clarifications, details of investigation, solution attempts and additional diagnostic information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like was mentioned in the comments, you haven't linked against `libm` so `sqrt` is undefined at link-time.

> Why would a constant value work for `sqrt`, while a variable user input value won't?

Because GCC recognizes `sqrt` as a [builtin function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) and is able to evaluate the square root of a compile-time constant at compilation time, and forgoes the call to `sqrt` altogether, thus avoiding the subsequent linker error.

> The ISO C90 functions ... `sqrt`, ... are all recognized as built-in functions unless `-fno-builtin` is specified (or `-fno-builtin-`*`function`* is specified for an individual function).

If you were to add `-fno-builtin-sqrt`, you would see the linker error regardless of what you pass to `sqrt`.

Answer (score 1):

Functions inside the `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h` have implementations in `libc.so` (or `libc.a` for static linking), which is linked into  executable by default (as if `-lc` were specified).

GCC can be instructed to avoid this automatic link with the `-nostdlib` or `-nodefaultlibs` options.

Functions in math.h have implementations in `libm.so` (or `libm.a` for static linking), and libm is not linked in by default.

Basically,  C++ runtime `libstdc++` requires `libm`, so if you compile a C++ program with GCC (g++), you will automatically get `libm` linked in.